# How do I keep initial value in a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to write code in Excel VBA, and I need the initial numeric value to stay the same until the string value changes, so that the last numeric value will be subtracted from the initial numeric value. After the string value changes, then a new initial numeric value is needed.

More specifically:
For a given stock ticker, I need to keep the opening price at the beginning of the year, and subtract it from the closing price at the end of the year, to find the yearly change. When the ticker changes, I then need a new beginning of the year opening price for the new stock. Unfortunately, the for loop I have written does not keep the same beginning of the year opening price, but instead subtracts the year end closing price from that same day's opening price (because they are in the same row i). I can't hard code the opening price, because it needs to change when the ticker changes.

Here is the code:

```
'Loop through all stock trades
For i = 2 To LastRow

    ' Set opening price
    Dim Opening_Price As Double
    Opening_Price = Cells(i, 3).Value


    ' Check if we are still within the same ticker.
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

      ' Set the ticker name
      Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value

      ' Print the ticker name in the Summary Table
      Range("I" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Ticker

      ' Add or subtract closing price from first opening price
      Yearly_Change = Cells(i, 6).Value - Opening_Price

      ' Print the change in stock price in the Summary Table
      Range("J" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Yearly_Change

      ' Calculate percent change from opening to closing price
      Percent_Change = (Yearly_Change / Opening_Price) * 100

      ' Print the percent change in the summary table
      Range("K" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Percent_Change

      ' Add one to the summary table row
      Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1


    End If



Next i
```

Comment: No, opening of year price for each stock is the first row of that stock name (ticker), with several stock names on the worksheet. Your later reply (that I accepted) answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yea I got it. Thanks for the click. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your issue. You need to specify when the loop is on a **new** "stock/ticker" or whatnot. An `if` statement that switches this to `True` or `False` should do it (assuming I understand your issue correctly).

See your modified code below (I removed items unrelated to your issue).

```
For i = 2 To LastRow

'Capture price if first of year
Dim stockPriceAlreadyCaptured As Boolean

    If stockPriceAlreadyCaptured = False Then
         'Set opening price
         Dim Opening_Price As Double
         Opening_Price = Cells(i, 3).Value

         'ensures no future prices captured until condition met.
         stockPriceAlreadyCaptured = True
    End If


    'Check if we are still within the same ticker.
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        '...unrelated code excluded

        'switch your condition back to capture next price line.
        stockPriceAlreadyCaptured = False

    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it outside of the for-loop:

```
' Set opening price
Dim Opening_Price As Double
Opening_Price = Cells(2, 3).Value

'Loop through all stock trades
For i = 2 To LastRow
```

Comment: Will this work for the new Opening_Price when the ticker changes?

Comment: @jason-hernandez-73 no it doesn't, but D Stanley's answer is the answer to what your LITERAL question is. You might consider rewording question to be "How to hold a value in a loop until a certain condition met" since you aren't just concerned about the first price, but all future new stocks/etc.